# Xlwings:- "AttributeError: module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'workBook'"

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

```
line 234, in query_and_export1
    xw.workBook().vba.add_module(vba_code)
AttributeError: module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'workBook'
```

i am trying to execute my vba script on queried data exported from database into an xlsx file .The aim of the Vba script is to display the queried data into a form that eases interpretation.My vba script is as thous

```
vba_code = '''
        Sub FormatSheet()
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Dim pt As PivotTable
            Dim pf As PivotField

            
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
            Set pt = ws.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Cells(1, 6), TableName:="MainPivotTable")

            ' Add ct_num and periode to the main table
            With pt
                .AddData Field:=ws.Range("A1").Column, Function:=xlSum
                .AddData Field:=ws.Range("B1").Column, Function:=xlSum
                .PivotFields("ct_num").Orientation = xlRowField
                .PivotFields("periode").Orientation = xlRowField
            End With

            ' Add Dl_MontantTTC to the main table
            With pt.PivotFields(ws.Range("D1").Column)
                .Orientation = xlDataField
                .Function = xlSum
                .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            End With

            ' Create a PivotTable for each year and month as a sub-table
            Dim yearField As PivotField
            Dim monthField As PivotField

            Set yearField = pt.PivotFields("periode")
            Set monthField = pt.PivotFields("periode")

            yearField.Orientation = xlPageField
            monthField.Orientation = xlPageField

            ' Set up a filter for the main table to show only the selected year
            With pt.PivotFields("periode")
                .Orientation = xlPageField
                .Position = 1
            End With

            ' Set up a filter for the main table to show only the selected ct_num
            With pt.PivotFields("ct_num")
                .Orientation = xlPageField
                .Position = 2
            End With

            ' Hide the field list
            ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
        End Sub
    '''
```

My xlwings library is up to date

Comment: Where is your python code. VBA code you try to execute is irrelevant. Module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'workBook' indeed

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing is `AttributeError: module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'workBook'`. This error is occurring because the `xlwings` module does not have an attribute or method named `workBook`.

In `xlwings`, to access a workbook, you should use `Book` or `books` depending on your use case. If you want to create a new workbook, you can use `xw.Book()`. If you want to access an existing workbook, you can use `xw.books['Your Workbook Name']`.

So, the line of code causing the error:

```py
xw.workBook().vba.add_module(vba_code)
```

should be changed to:

```py
xw.Book().vba.add_module(vba_code)
```

or if you're working with an existing workbook:

```py
xw.books['Your Workbook Name'].vba.add_module(vba_code)
```

Please replace `'Your Workbook Name'` with the actual name of your workbook¹. I hope this helps!